# Scaling an input range by minimum in (upcoming) C++23 (using zip_transform and repeat)

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

In [ADSP Podcast Episode 91](https://adspthepodcast.com/2022/08/19/Episode-91.html) (2022-08-19, around 14:30 ... 16:30) Bryce Lelbach and Conor Hoekstra talk about an example application of the (hopefully) upcoming C++23 ranges views `zip_transform` and `repeat`: scaling a range of values by the (non-zero) minimum value of that range.

Since to my knowledge at the time of writing, no library of any compiler implements these yet (and no link was given), I wonder how to implement it. The closest I came up with, was

```
auto scale_by_min(auto&& range)
{
    auto m = std::ranges::min(range);
    return std::views::zip_transform(
        range,
        std::views::repeat(m),
        [](auto x, auto min)
        {
            return x / min;
        }
    );
}
```

([(non-working) example in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9drosnr73)). Did I get it right?

**Edit / Clarification:**

Replacing the return statement by

```
return range | std::views::transform([m](auto x){ return x / m; });
```

it works in C++20, also without `zip_transform` and `repeat`, as correctly stated in a comment. This question is not about conciseness, style, or meaningfulness of the example. I just try to get the syntax right for using the upcoming ranges-views.

Comment: Why not just simply `return range |  std::views::transform([m](auto x) { return x / m; });`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I get it right?

No. `zip_transform` accepts variadic template arguments as input ranges, the first argument of `zip_transform` must be the transform functor, so you should

```
auto m = std::ranges::min(range);
return std::views::zip_transform(
  std::divides{},
  range,
  std::views::repeat(m)
);
```

It's worth noting that `views::repeat(m)` gives you an infinite range, which makes `zip_transform_view` not model `sized_range`. You can pass the second parameter of `repeat_view` by detecting whether the `range` is `sized_range`, e.g.

```
auto m = std::ranges::min(range);
auto repeat = [&] {
  if constexpr (std::ranges::sized_range<decltype(range)>)
    return std::views::repeat(m, std::ranges::size(range));
  else
    return std::views::repeat(m);
}();
return std::views::zip_transform(std::divides{}, range, repeat);
```

which makes `zip_transform_view` preserve the properties of `sized_range`.